# TypeScript: 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I'm writing a React application using TypeScript. I use material-ui for my components. I'm currently writing a wrapper for material-ui's input like this:

```
import FormControl, { FormControlProps } from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import MUIInput, { InputProps } from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel, { InputLabelProps } from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import classNames from "classnames";
import React, { PureComponent, ReactNode } from "react";
import styles from "./styles";

export interface OwnProps {
  labelText?: ReactNode;
  labelProps?: InputLabelProps;
  id?: string;
  inputProps?: InputProps;
  formControlProps?: FormControlProps;
  inputRootCustomClasses?: string;
  success?: boolean;
  white?: boolean;
  error?: boolean;
}

export interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, OwnProps {}

export class Input extends PureComponent<Props> {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      formControlProps,
      labelText,
      id,
      labelProps,
      inputProps,
      error,
      white,
      inputRootCustomClasses,
      success
    } = this.props;
    const labelClasses = classNames({
      [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
      [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
    });
    const underlineClasses = classNames({
      [classes.underlineError]: error,
      [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
      [classes.underline]: true,
      [classes.whiteUnderline]: white
    });
    const marginTop = classNames({
      [inputRootCustomClasses!]: inputRootCustomClasses !== undefined
    });
    const inputClasses = classNames({
      [classes.input]: true,
      [classes.whiteInput]: white
    });
    let formControlClasses;
    if (formControlProps !== undefined) {
      formControlClasses = classNames(formControlProps.className, classes.formControl);
    } else {
      formControlClasses = classes.formControl;
    }
    return (
      <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlClasses}>
        {labelText !== undefined ? (
          <InputLabel
            className={classes.labelRoot + " " + labelClasses}
            htmlFor={id}
            {...labelProps}
          >
            {labelText}
          </InputLabel>
        ) : null}
        <Input
          classes={{
            disabled: classes.disabled,
            input: inputClasses,
            root: marginTop,
            underline: underlineClasses
          }}
          id={id}
          {...inputProps}
        />
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Input);
```

I have a problem with this `<Input />`'s properties:

```
classes={{
  disabled: classes.disabled,
  input: inputClasses,
  root: marginTop,
  underline: underlineClasses
}}
```

For disabled, inputt throws the error:

```
[ts]
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. I tried `as`:

```
underline: underlineClasses as string
```

Doesn't work. I tried using the `!` operator to assert not-null, but it doesn't work. The weirdest thing about it is that the function `classNames` always returns a string (even if its empty). Furthermore classes.disabled is also always defined, since its included within my `styles`.

How can I solve this? I'm developing in strict mode so this linter hickup crashes my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own error ‍♂️ I accidentally wrote `<Input />` again instead of `<MUIInput />`.

```
<MUIInput
  classes={{
    disabled: classes.disabled,
    input: inputClasses,
    root: marginTop,
    underline: underlineClasses
  }}
  id={id}
  {...inputProps}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, a property on a object can be undefined and you input prop in this case needs a string so, a way to fix is:

```
classes={{
   disabled: classes.disabled,
   input: inputClasses,
   root: marginTop,
   underline: underlineClasses || ''
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. After reading your answer I tried both: `classes.disabled || 'false'` and `classes.disabled || 'undefined'`. I also tried passing these as literally `false` or `undefined` (not as a string). The errors remain.

Comment: Your problem is with the disabled or underline property ?